# Algoritmo de planificacion fifo

Tags: java

Necesito hacer el algoritmo de planificación `fifo`, lo estoy haciendo en `Java` pero estoy estancando en la parte de los procesos a organizar, tengo dos `Array` uno con el tiempo de llegada y el otro con el tiempo de `rafagaCpu` o tiempo de servicio, pero al organizar el tiempo de llegada con un `Sort` no sé como hacer que el `Array rafagaCpu` se acomode al nuevo orden de tiempo de llegada para ser mas explicito lo mostrare así.

```
1. P1 5 6
2. P2 2 4
3. P3 0 3
4. P4 3 7
```

Donde la primera columna son los procesos, la segunda, tiempo de llegada y la tercera es la Rafaga de cpu.

Cuando aplico `Sort` el orden cambia solo para la segunda columna

```
1. P1 0 6
2. P2 2 4
3. P3 3 3
4. P4 5 7
```

Necesito que la tercera también lo haga pero no sé como

```
 int tiempoLlegada[] = new int[numeroProcesos];
    int rafagaCpu[] = new int[numeroProcesos];

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroProcesos; i++) {
        tiempoLlegada[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Tiempo de llegada del proceso "+(i+1)));

        for (int j=0;i<numeroProcesos;j++){
            rafagaCpu[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Rafaga de Cpu del proceso "+(i+1)));
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(tiempoLlegada);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución sería emplear un método clásico [Burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) , podría ordenar los dos arreglos en paralelo , ordenamos el `array` `tiempoLlegada` si se modifica el orden de este , también modificamos el orden de los elementos de  `rafagaCpu`.  *(explicación detallada en el enlace)*

```
int[] tiempoLlegada = new int[]{ 16 , 4 , 18 ,12 ,1,6};
int[] rafagaCpu = new int[]{ 6 , 14 , 8 ,2,11 ,66}; 
int tmp = 0 ;
for (int j = 1; j < tiempoLlegada.length; j++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < tiempoLlegada.length-1; i++) {
       if(tiempoLlegada[i]>tiempoLlegada[i+1]){
          tmp = tiempoLlegada[i];
          tiempoLlegada[i] = tiempoLlegada[i+1];
          tiempoLlegada[i+1]= tmp;
          tmp = rafagaCpu[i];
          rafagaCpu[i] = rafagaCpu[i+1];
          rafagaCpu[i+1]= tmp;
       }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tiempoLlegada));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rafagaCpu));
```

**Salida**

```
[1, 4, 6, 12, 16, 18]
[11, 14, 66, 2, 6, 8]
```

> Tener en cuenta que con este método , dentro del `if` puede modificar
>   `Arrays` de cualquier tipo de dato , pero debe crear la variable `tmp`
>   de acuerdo al tipo del `Array`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta esto es lo que necesitaba, disculpa que te haga esta pregunta soy muy nuevo en la programacion me recomendarias alguna guia para resolver problemas como este

Comment: La solución de este problema sería más sencillo si se utilizará `Objetos`. y los valores que guardas en `array` serían atributos , una guía rápida puede leer http://codehero.co/java-desde-cero-clases-y-objectos/  aunque en google hay mucha información sobre esto.

Comment: @FelipePeña no olvidar si mi respuesta resolvió sus problemas , aceptar mi respuesta así no queda abierta la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Perdona se me paso